# Scala SyncVar usage of isDefined flag

Tags: scala, concurrency

Looking at the implementation of `scala.concurrent.SyncVar[A]` in Scala we see the following declarations:

```
class SyncVar[A] {
  private var isDefined: Boolean = false
  private var value: Option[A] = None
 ...
```

Could we replace all the usages of the `isDefined` member with a call to `value.isDefined` and expect the same behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since all accesses to `isDefined` occur within `synchronized` blocks, indicating that we can reason about the state of `SyncVar` sequentially within those blocks, and since `isDefined` is always assigned if and only if the `Option[T]` field `value` is also assigned (in methods `setVal` and `unsetVal`), it follows that `isDefined` and `value.isDefined` are equivalent.

The current design is probably a remnant from the [olden days](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/95a9b8dc2e7b0050e6254ac114e4d2ea58512d96), when the `value` field was not an `Option[T]` reference, but a reference of type `T`.

EDIT:
Digging a bit, it turns out that the change was by @phaller, and [reviewed by myself](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/74062e352955afa6869636d84035011e3518d7d4). The change was to avoid memory leaks. In retrospect, we probably could have just nulled out the `T` field instead of replacing it with an `Option[T]`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/70f0b1ded880ec9b3a9478d02f1898fcfeee230c/src/library/scala/concurrent/SyncVar.scala) for `SyncVar`, one can see that all the public methods are `synchronized` including these that change those two variables, and that whenever `isDefined` becomes `false`, `value` becomes `None`, and whenever `isDefined` becomes `true`, `value` has `Some(value)` with the value. Given that the variables are private to the class, you can be assured that all these conditions will always be true.